# How do I use the value of provider default tags in a data source or resource block in terraform?

Tags: terraform, tags, terraform-provider-aws

Below is a small snippet of a set of terraform script I'm trying to build. The goal is to define an IAM policy that will be attached to a new IAM role that I will create.

My problem is I'm trying to use the environment tag that I've defined in my AWS provider's `default_tags` block but I'm not sure how. The goal is to pull the environment value as part of the S3 prefix in the IAM policy document instead of having it hard coded.

Is there a way to do this?

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "4.19.0"
    }
  }
  required_version = ">=1.2.3"
}

provider "aws" {
  default_tags {
      tags = {
        Environment = "dev"
        Application = "myapp"
        Terraform = "true"
      }
    }
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "this" {

  statement {
    sid = "S3BucketAccess"
    actions = "s3:*"
    resources = [
      "${data.aws_s3_bucket.this.arn}/dev"
    ]
  }
}

data "aws_s3_bucket" "this" {
  bucket = "myBucket"
}
```

Notice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution without code duplication is to use [`aws_default_tags`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/default_tags):

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "4.19.0"
    }
  }
  required_version = ">=1.2.3"
}

provider "aws" {
  default_tags {
      tags = {
        Environment = "dev"
        Application = "myapp"
        Terraform = "true"
      }
    }
}

# Get the default tags from the provider
data "aws_default_tags" "my_tags" {}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "this" {
  statement {
    sid = "S3BucketAccess"
    actions = "s3:*"
    resources = ["${data.aws_s3_bucket.this.arn}/${data.aws_default_tags.my_tags.tags.Environment}/*"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ervin Szilagyi, I've accepted your solution as it there's less code to maintain with your solution over mine.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use [locals](https://www.terraform.io/language/values/locals#declaring-a-local-value).

Here's how the final solution looks like

```
# New locals block

locals {
    common_tags = {
       Environment = "dev"
       Application = "myapp"
       Terraform = "true"
    }
}

terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "4.19.0"
    }
  }
  required_version = ">=1.2.3"
}

provider "aws" {
  # Reference common_tags from locals

  default_tags {
      tags = local.common_tags
    }
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "this" {

  # In the resources statement, I replaced 
  # "dev" prefix with Environment tag value using locals 

  statement {
    sid = "S3BucketAccess"
    actions = "s3:*"
    resources = ["${data.aws_s3_bucket.this.arn}/${local.common_tags.Environment}/*"
    ]
  }
}

data "aws_s3_bucket" "this" {
  bucket = "myBucket"
}
```

Comment: There is also a data source for this: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/default_tags.

Comment: @MarkoE please provide it as an answer next time instead of a comment. Otherwise, this will get lost here (also, I was writing my answer, while you added this comment).

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi I was about to start writing the answer, came back here and saw there was already an answer to the question by the same person so figured there is not much for me to do. :) But point taken!